# Replacing text in Paragraph Open XML

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml

I have multiple paragraphs in slide with placeholders <<>>, i need to replace the placeholder with actual text, however after replacement if i inspect the file with open xml SDK, i see the below line

```
 A.Run run54 = new A.Run();
 OpenXmlUnknownElement openXmlUnknownElement2 = OpenXmlUnknownElement.CreateOpenXmlUnknownElement("<p:text xmlns:p=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main\">Placeholder replaced Text</p:text>");
 run54.Append(openXmlUnknownElement2);
```

if i actually open the file, the repair dialog appears and content goes away

below is the code i am using to replace the text

```
  if (paragraph.InnerText.Contains(originalText))
                {
                    D.ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties6 = new D.ParagraphProperties() { Alignment = D.TextAlignmentTypeValues.Center };
                    D.DefaultRunProperties defaultRunProperties24 = new D.DefaultRunProperties();

                    paragraphProperties6.Append(defaultRunProperties24);

                    D.Run run6 = new D.Run();
                    D.RunProperties runProperties8 = new D.RunProperties() { Language = "en-US", FontSize = 2400, Bold = true };
                    runProperties8.SetAttribute(new OpenXmlAttribute("", "smtClean", "", "0"));
                    D.SolidFill solidFill72 = new D.SolidFill();

                    D.RgbColorModelHex rgbColorModelHex16 = new D.RgbColorModelHex() { Val = "808080" };
                    D.LuminanceModulation luminanceModulation1 = new D.LuminanceModulation() { Val = 75000 };
                    rgbColorModelHex16.Append(luminanceModulation1);
                    solidFill72.Append(rgbColorModelHex16);
                    runProperties8.Append(solidFill72);
                    string modifiedString = Regex.Replace(paragraph.InnerText, originalText, ReplaceText);
                    paragraph.RemoveAllChildren<Run>();
                    paragraph.AppendChild<Run>(new Run(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.Text(modifiedString)));
                    //D.Text text15 = new D.Text();
                    //text15.Text = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.Text(modifiedString).ToString();
                    run6.Append(runProperties8);
                    //run6.Append(text15);
                    D.EndParagraphRunProperties endParagraphRunProperties7 = new D.EndParagraphRunProperties() { Language = "en-US", FontSize = 2400, Bold = true, Dirty = false };
                    endParagraphRunProperties7.SetAttribute(new OpenXmlAttribute("", "smtClean", "", "0"));
                    D.SolidFill solidFill75 = new D.SolidFill();

                    D.RgbColorModelHex rgbColorModelHex19 = new D.RgbColorModelHex() { Val = "808080" };
                    D.LuminanceModulation luminanceModulation4 = new D.LuminanceModulation() { Val = 75000 };

                    rgbColorModelHex19.Append(luminanceModulation4);

                    solidFill75.Append(rgbColorModelHex19);
                    endParagraphRunProperties7.Append(solidFill75);
                    paragraph.Append(paragraphProperties6);
                    paragraph.Append(run6);
                    //paragraph11.Append(break1);
                    paragraph.Append(endParagraphRunProperties7);
                    break;
                }
```

any help would be appreciated,

Comment: Have you tried using the TextReplacer.SearchAndReplace(...) in https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenXmlPowerTools/ ?

Comment: @DeveloperGuo-it says searchandreplace in docx.i will see if it also works on PPTX

Comment: It has an overload for PresentationDocument.

Answer (score 0):

Using openxml sdk to reflected code is quite good to checkout missing stuff but the code is hard to read and if you make one mistake copying it can result in a lots of free time loss.

So basically you have to know the structure of openxml elements which is the same for both word/powerpoint. It is paragraph|run|text here I ignore parent of paragraph which in word most of the times is TextBody.

First you have to find your search pattern in Run elements. Let's say that text isn't split into multiple Run elements.

```
IEnumerable<Run> runs = Paragraph.Descendants<Run>()
    .Where(el => el.InnerText.Contains("<<>>"));
if(runs != null) {
    foreach(Run run in runs) { 
        // Use this if using powerpoint openxml
        run.Text = new Text(run.InnerText.Replace("<<>>", "your text");

        // Use this if using wordprocessing openxml
        string innerText = run.InnerText.Replace("<<>>", "your text");
        run.RemoveAllChildren<Text>();
        run.AppendChild(new Text(innerText));
    }
}
```

And if the pattern is splitted into multiple runs you will have to iterate all paragraph runs and add each run text to local variable after finding the whole pattern you can replace those Runs text. I think you will manage to do this.